# Is Namenode format in pseudo distribution mode is necessary everytime

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

For the pseudo distribution mode in **Hadoop 2.6.0** do we have to format namenode everytime.

I am using hadoop 2.6.0 at my home but every time i use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh i have to format my namenode.

Is there is any other way to implement for avoiding this? Plz suggest me something to get out of this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to always format the NameNode even in the pseudo distributed mode. It's not recommended to format the NameNode more than once except when NameNode loses metadata information.

The reason could be this: property which tells NameNode where to store its metadata information on disk is `dfs.name.dir` (deprecated) or `dfs.namenode.name.dir` which by default points to `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name` which in-turn points to `/tmp/dfs/name` so every time you restart your system the `/tmp` directory gets cleared and hence you have to format the NameNode again.

So, make sure you point the property `dfs.namenode.name.dir` to a more persistent location which does not get's cleared.

Comment: will try and get back to you :)

Comment: I tried it by creating value of `dfs.namenode.name.dir` as `/usr/local/hadoop/tmp` but again after formatting the namenode i lose all my data.

Comment: You shouldn't format the NameNode more than once if you format command again then NameNode will erase all the metadata, think of NameNode formatting as formatting your hard drive.

Comment: So i have to change the `dfs.datanode.data.dir` also ?

Comment: Yes you should also change dfs.datanode.data.dir to make sure you don't lose data. Let me put it this way NN stores metadata information and DN's store actual data blocks. So formatting the NameNode will erase all metadata information from NameNode but data in datanode's will not be cleared but is not usable because no one has the information to collect the blocks from multiple datanode's for a file.

Comment: After changing dfs.datanode.data.dir  to a new location datanode is not starting now

Comment: I used [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25605985/3703079) its get solved, can you let me know is this a right way?

Comment: Yeah that's proper because you have been changing the directories on a running cluster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70465/discussion-between-pulse-and-ashrith).